# Messed up with android-studio and android-sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm trying to setup minimal environment for Android development on Arch linux. I've installed the following AUR packages: android-sdk, android-sdk-platform-tools, android-sdk-build-tools and android-studio.
I see that they were installed under `/opt/android-s{dk,studio}` directories. It was quite smooth so far, but when I start Android studio, it ask me where I want to place my working directory which I set to `~/Android`. After I installed some platform API (which unfortunately didn't installed successfully) I see that the directory structure and files under `/opt/android-sdk` and `~/Android/Sdk/` are quite similar:

```
ls /opt/android-sdk
add-ons  build-tools  platforms  platform-tools  sources  system-images  temp  tools


ls ~/Android/Sdk/
add-ons  build-tools  extras  licenses  platforms  platform-tools  'SDK Readme.txt'  skins  sources  system-images  tools
```

So, where is some kind of **primary** directory for installing all of the Android environment tools? I can't get the relation between installing packages through Android studio and `android sdk` command. It seems like they duplicate each other.

In addition, what about setting the follwoing env variables:

```
#Is this correct in my case? 
#Also, what is the difference? I didn't find information on this.
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
```

One of the reason of the questioning is necessity to move `/opt/adnroid-*` folders into another directory (take too much space).
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one "Android" directory. When you installed AS it probably installed a new copy of the SDK in the user directory.

Try changing the SDK location in AS settings to /opt/android-sdk and deleting the ~/Android directory. Then set both ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to /opt/android-sdk.

Or do it backwards and delete the one in /opt folder if you like having it in the user directory.